# swims through the river

Tags: grammar

We say a person swims across a river.(From this side to that side.) 
If he is completely submerged in the water when he swims, can we say "he swims through the river"?

Comment: No, we can't. "Through" does not tell us his relative position in the water.

Comment: @Greybeard That's not right. It's idiomatic to say *he walks through the room* or *he swims through the water*. So, questions about "relative position" cannot be why we don't say *he swims through the river*. There's something about the specific use of *river* that's the problem, not the general construction of the sentence.

Comment: "he walks through the room", does it mean he walks into the room through a door and walks out of the room through another door at the other side?

Comment: @Jason Bassford. It is idiomatic to say "he swims through the water". But it is not idiomatic to say "he swims through the river". Is that what you meant? Why?

Comment: @StephenLiu Yes, that's what I mean. I have no idea why *through the* ***water*** is fine, but *through the* ***river*** is not. (Especially when *through the* ***room*** is also fine. So it can't be about, or completely about, the use of mass noun.)

Comment: @JasonBassford you may have missed the significance of *If he is completely submerged in the water when he swims, can we say "he swims through the river"?*, which implies that *through* in some way indicates submersion. ++ You said *There's something about the specific use of **river** that's the problem,*  As the question is about *through*, you might agree that it would be helpful to concentrate on that.

Comment: @Greybeard No, I didn't. Whether he is submerged or not, *he swims through the water* still works, and what many people would actually say to describe the situation. *Through* has nothing to do with submersion (or immersion) in either of the acceptable sentences I've mentioned in my comments, with each using a different noun.

Comment: @JasonBassford That would make me wonder why Stephen Liu mentioned "underwater".

Comment: @Greybeard It's irrelevant to any answer. The distinction between *across* and *through* is what raised the question. The general answer is that *through* is just fine, and a reasonable assumption. But it's ***not*** fine when the specific noun is *river*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I think not.I suspect that the OP knows that *The general answer is that **through** is just fine.* but wants to know about the preposition if submerged.

Comment: No. I think the general answer is across the river. I was asking whether "through the river" could work. Why did I mention underwater? Because "through" something generally refers to being in/inside something while in motion, according to my experience.